# Postgres on Ubuntu Server 16.04 - automatically backups

Tags: database, ubuntu, postgresql

I have Ubuntu Server 16.04 and PostgreSql database. How to organize automatically backups? Is this better idea to move my database to AWS RDS instead having database on my server?

Comment: Are you asking this from a security perspective? What are the current options you have? Do you have some thoughts about what's best yourself?

Comment: This looks more like an operational question than a security question.

Comment: What will AWS RDS do for you that your current solution won't?

Answer (score 0):

> How to organize automatically backups?

One solution would be a shell script in that you first make a compressed dump. Give it a meaningful filename (and date within).  Than you could rsync this dump to some backup storage. By putting this script into the cron table you have you're automatic backup solution. At this point it doesn't make a difference between your local server or an AWS instance i.e.

> Is this better idea to move my database to AWS RDS instead having database on my server?

This depends on your needs. If you do not have the requirement to talk to the database from everywhere I would always prefer the local solution but I guess to give an answer that fits one would need more information what you want to do with the database.

p.s.
For me it looks like a question for the super user community or are you interested in specific security questions here?

Comment: thanks, well.. I have web application on that server and do not have the requirement to talk to the database from everywhere. Should I somehow encrypt database dump files? What is the best solution to do this? "rsync this dump to some backup storage" - Do you mean another VPS server or for example AWS S3? Looking for most secure solution.